# Automator can't find bash command

Tags: command-line, bash, automator

I'm trying to make an action on Automator that recursively batch  processes PNG images using bash shell script with `pngquant`

I have done this on terminal and got no problem, but now I want to make a finder action using Automator.

This is the shell script code (receives a directory input):

```
directory="$1"
cd $directory
find . -name '*.png' -exec pngquant --ext .png --force 256 {} \;
```

I'm having trouble with `pngquant` as it says:

```
pngquant: command not found
```